# resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored not found

Tags: android

When I want to try the application on the emulator or extract the `.apk`

I face this error

```
Android resource linking failed
error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored not found.
error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored not found.
error: failed linking references.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your are applying that style wrong.

Try to set the style of your view in your layout (.xml file) this way:

```
style="@style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored"
```

Let me know if that helped!